# TypeScript advanced type checks

Tags: typescript

Check please the comments in the code. Is it possible to get what I want or TS has no such functionality?

I need type checks for my `addToRegistry` function.

[TypeScript playground with code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20MessageHandler%3CT%3E%20%3D%20((data%3A%20T)%20%3D%3E%20void)%20%7C%20((data%3A%20T)%20%3D%3E%20Promise%3Cvoid%3E)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20AuthPayload%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20id%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20HandlersRegistry%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20auth%3F%3A%20MessageHandler%3CAuthPayload%3E%3B%0D%0A%20%20test%3F%3A%20MessageHandler%3Cnumber%3E%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20registry%20%3D%20new%20HandlersRegistry()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20handler%20type%20should%20ref%20on%20HandlersRegistry%5Bkey%5D%20by%20eventType%0D%0Afunction%20addToRegistry%3CT%3E(eventType%3A%20keyof%20HandlersRegistry%2C%20handler%3A%20MessageHandler%3CT%3E)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20registry%5BeventType%5D%20%3D%20handler%3B%20%2F%2F%20should%20not%20be%20an%20error%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20authHandler%3A%20MessageHandler%3CAuthPayload%3E%20%3D%20(data%3A%20AuthPayload)%20%3D%3E%20null%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20correct%0D%0AaddToRegistry('auth'%2C%20authHandler)%3B%0D%0A%2F%2F%20correct%2C%20shows%20error%2C%20but%20I%20don't%20want%20to%20provide%20type%20of%20payload%20every%20time%0D%0AaddToRegistry%3Cnumber%3E('test'%2C%20authHandler)%3B%0D%0A%2F%2F%20should%20show%20error%2C%20but%20doesn't%0D%0AaddToRegistry('test'%2C%20authHandler)%3B%0D%0A)

```
type MessageHandler<T> = ((data: T) => void) | ((data: T) => Promise<void>);

interface AuthPayload {
    id: string;
}

class HandlersRegistry {
    auth?: MessageHandler<AuthPayload>;
    test?: MessageHandler<number>;
}

const registry = new HandlersRegistry();

// handler type should ref on HandlersRegistry[key] by eventType
// function addToRegistry<T>(eventType: keyof HandlersRegistry, handler: ???) {
function addToRegistry<T>(eventType: keyof HandlersRegistry, handler: MessageHandler<T>) {
    registry[eventType] = handler; // should not be an error
}

const authHandler: MessageHandler<AuthPayload> = (data: AuthPayload) => null;

// correct
addToRegistry('auth', authHandler);
// correct, shows error, but I don't want to provide type of payload every time
addToRegistry<number>('test', authHandler);
// should show error, but doesn't
addToRegistry('test', authHandler);
```

Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a generic type to hold the type of the key and a type query to specify the parameter must be the same type as the field type:

```
type MessageHandler<T> = ((data: T) => void) | ((data: T) => Promise<void>);

interface AuthPayload {
    id: string;
}

class HandlersRegistry {
    auth?: MessageHandler<AuthPayload>;
    test?: MessageHandler<number>;
}

const registry = new HandlersRegistry();

// handler type should ref on HandlersRegistry[key] by eventType
// function addToRegistry<T>(eventType: keyof HandlersRegistry, handler: ???) {
function addToRegistry<K extends keyof HandlersRegistry>(eventType: K, handler: HandlersRegistry[K]) {
    registry[eventType] = handler; // should not be an error
}

const authHandler: MessageHandler<AuthPayload> = (data: AuthPayload) => null;

// correct
addToRegistry('auth', authHandler);
// correct, shows error, but I don't want to provide type of payload every time
addToRegistry<number>('test', authHandler);
// show error as expected
addToRegistry('test', authHandler);
```